# Note taking extension on vscode that helps programming?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to programming, during learning I face problems like I don't fully understand some part of codes in a complex program, therefore I need to write down what I don't understand somewhere, and retrieve/review codes&my questions later. Therefore I'm looking for a vscode extension or software that can implement those functions:

1. comment on code
2. overview on my written comments(I want to go through everything I write down in one place)
3. jump to the location in codes where I write this comment

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: A code file can be opened by multiple developers using different IDEs. And since comments are freeform there is not a single generally accepted norm on how to do standardized comments. Generally accepted norm is to comment using ''//TODO:'' prefix. You can find vscode extension to manage TODO comments.

Comment: "comment on code" - why not write a comment to the code in the most usual way: as a comment on the code?

Comment: in the VSC extension examples there is a comment extension, it saves comments in a different location (database) then the source file